Responding to Berkeley's Likeness principle
I would really appreciate some ideas regarding possible responses to Berkeley's Likeness principle as an attack against representative/indirect realism. My understanding of the role of the Likeness principle is that, as mind-dependent ideas cannot be anything like mind-independent objects (they cannot conceivably be compared), they cannot be said to resemble each other. As resemblance is a precondition for representation, the immediate objects of perception cannot represent mind-independent objects. How might one respond to this argument?
I suppose one idea would be to deny the claim that resemblance is a necessary condition for representation. Alternatively, perhaps one could claim that inconceivability does not necessarily serve as a guide to impossibility, and in fact mind-dependent ideas may be like mind-independent objects. How might these objections be fleshed out?
Unfortunately, I can't seem to find very many good resources (I am currently in high school and don't have access to much more than JSTOR). Please do let me know if I have misunderstood anything obvious. Also, feel free to point me towards readily available resources given that this is surely a question which has been discussed extensively in the literature.

Berkeley equivocates on "resemblance". In the sense that mind-dependent ideas cannot "resemble" mind-independent objects "resemblance" is not a a precondition for representation, and in the sense that it is, ideas can "resemble" objects. All that is needed is that immediate percepts preserve relations among objects, this does not require "comparing" them to establish the "resemblance", the relations can be tested by interacting with the objects. Representationalism does not need objects to be immediately perceivable in a fully faithful manner.

Dicker reconstructs Berkeley's arguments for the likeness principle and gives rebuttals, but you'll probably only be able to access the abstract.

I'd like to point out that if you really want to understand the world, you should start by learning FOL (first-order logic) and not by trying to understand philosophy, most of which is not worth even reading. It's good that you seem to have a keen intuition, but you need to solidify it in actual logic.

You might respond by considering it to be irrelevant. You might take the view that mind-independent objects exist, and that mind-dependent ideas exist, and the there can be a correspondence between an object and an idea that is sufficient for us to make sense of the world. If you encounter a teapot, you form an idea of its size, shape, position orientation, surface properties, temperature, etc through your senses of sight and touch, and that experience is sufficient to differentiate the teapot from a neighbouring cup, about which your form a separate idea. Clearly the idea of the teapot is like a map of a terrain, which is nothing like the terrain itself in some respects, but is a good guide to it in others.

And, everybody can recognize a teapot if they have seen teapots before, without knowing that it is made up of exactly the same kind of electrons, protons and neutrons as tea!

Here's an answer that I suspect most people aren't going to like, but won't be able to refute. Namely, there is no good response to Berkeley's likeness principle. I am convinced that the principle is sound.
It's not that Berkeley thinks resemblance is a necessary precondition for representation. Indeed, Berkeley's view of the mind is that ideas, qua phenomenal experiences, cannot be like the mind. Yet, we can still use the word 'mind', a sensible thing (you just saw and mentally processed the word 'mind'), to represent the non-sensible mind (check out Principles of Human Knowledge sect. 27, among many other places, for this point). So, if one can come up with a coherent, positive notion, or definition, of what one means by the word 'matter', then one can represent "matter", thus defined.
Hence, most notions one can have of 'matter' will not be undercut by the likeness principle. That is why Berkeley spills much ink rejecting different notions one might have of the word 'matter' (see for instance Principles of Human Knowledge sections 67-81, and the first and second dialogue of Three Dialogues Between Hylas and Philonous). Berkeley polemicizes the likeness principle against a particular notion of what 'matter' purportedly means only at Principles sect. 8, and in the last couple pages of the first dialogue.
Accordingly, Berkeley's likeness principle is not supposed to undercut most definitions of 'matter', nor many ways we can use the word 'matter' to represent whatever one thinks 'matter' means. The likeness principle is only supposed to undercut the view that "matter" is something perceived "mediately", or "indirectly"; and, insofar as "mediately perceived" matter resembles "immediately perceived" mind-dependent ideas, is insofar as matter is represented by ideas.
The view of what 'matter' means, thus described, is a resemblance-based version of indirect/representational realism. Such a view is commonly ascribed, in some degree, to Descartes, Locke, and Malebranche, among others. Those thinkers deny that all immediately perceived sensible qualities resemble matter, but maintain that certain ('primary') qualities, do. The likeness principle undercuts any resemblance-based version of indirect realism.
The undercutting is simple. What does it mean to say that redness is perceivable? We see it, or can in the right situation (like turning on the light). What about square, or cubical shape? That we see or feel it (or would if we were situated close enough to the object to touch it). How about taking up space? That we see or feel it (and, perhaps, echolocate it, or would do any of these things if properly situated). What about a symphony? That we hear it (or would in the right scenario). What about the taste of chocolate, or salt? That we taste it (or would if we got a hold of some). What about the smell of a rose, curdled milk, or fresh-made pie? That we smell it (or could). These things are all done immediately, and all occur when we perceive the kinds of ideas in the world, which are described by physics, and that we all agree exist and could be perceived by one another, so situated to do so.
What about imagined perceptions, or perceptions in a dream, or hallucination? Again, they have phenomenal character. They may be red or blue, tall or small, hard or soft, smelly or tasty, hot or cold, etc. But, again, there is something identifiable in the experience we have of them that demarcates them as being perceived. That is, as (both Berkeley, and) resemblance-based indirect realists stipulate, both our immediate sensations of the public world of physics, and our private mental perceptions of the imagination, are mind-dependent, and everything about their existence is contained in our very perception(s) thereof. In short, their esse is percipi; their existence, as perceived by us, is nothing but the perception(s) we have of them. That is, they are identifiable by and identical to the perception(s) we have of them.
Now, what does it mean to say that matter is mediately perceivable, and represented by our ideas (perceptions) insofar as they resemble our ideas (perceptions)? If matter is supposed to be insensible, invisible, intangible, etc., to anyone, then in which sense does matter resemble something sensible, visible, tangible, etc.? If matter is supposed to be sensible, then Berkeley may as well ask: in which respect? If matter is supposed to have shape, then Berkeley will ask which kind of shape we are speaking of- the one we only ever perceive visually, and/or tangibly? If yes, then haven't we just granted that matter is an idea, since only ideas are sensible to us?
You may reply that matter is still perceived, but not in the sense that ideas are. Matter is perceived indirectly, nevertheless. But then, in what respect is that matter perceived? "Insofar as that matter resembles our ideas". Okay, and in which respect(s) does matter resemble our ideas? "Insofar as they are extended (occupy an area of space), and have shape." Okay, so then matter is extended and has shape then? "Yes." Okay, so then we are able to immediately perceive the area of space matter occupies, and the shape it has, then? "No, for that would contradict our theory of perception". Ah, but surely God could immediately perceive that matter? If yes, then matter is an idea, by your own lights. If no, then I ask, "in which area of space doth matter occupy? And what is its shape?" If you say "it occupies the area of space we see ideas in, and has the very shape of its correspondent ideas", then matter is an idea. For, there is only one thing we can identify at any given location, with any given shape, and that thing is an idea, by your admissions. And, if that matter exists somewhere else, I ask where, and, once located, what shape does it have? If you say it has neither, then matter doesn't resemble our ideas. If you say it has some shape and some location, then I ask which and where. If you give me a shape and a location, then, I ask, is it not an idea we see there and with that shape? If it is, then it is not matter, but an idea. If that shape and location is not perceivable by any mind, then, in what sense is that matter perceivable, with a perceivable shape and location? Insofar as its shape and location resemble our ideas thereof? "I think I'm going to be sick. Operator, get me off this accursed Merry-Go-Round (says Berkeley)!"
The basic problem with a resemblance-based theory of indirect realism is that the it fails for either of two reasons (as is noted in Principles 8). Either it is flat out contradictory (by postulating that matter is insensible, while resembling something sensible), or else by asserting something vacuous- an empty word- nothing (by applying the word 'perceived' to matter, when the only thing perceived are ideas {and nothing else}).
We cannot give positive signification (i.e. only empty words can be used) to describe something that does not exist so defined without contradiction or vacuity. To say that one is capable of conceiving that something actually is sensible, without something sensible being present to our imagination, or presented directly to our senses, or capable of being perceived in the right situation, is not to conceive of something sensible at all, but to delude ourselves with empty words, without a meaning, nor perceptibility thereto.
If we imagine, dream, or conjure up some sort of perception in our mind, then we've only imagined an idea (this is stipulated by the materialist in this case). Hence, while we can say the words 'matter resembles that', Berkeley may as well ask what matter we are speaking about. Now we are trapped. If we say something that resembles our ideas, then Berkeley may as well ask which something is it that resembles our ideas. If we say matter, then Berkeley may as well ask what matter we are talking about. Etc.
But we haven't pictured matter, only an idea. Why? Because all imaginations are in some way copies or resemblances of immediately perceived perceptions. No person born blind can picture color; yet we who read these words with eyes that can see, do. For, we have immediately perceived color now and before. Hence, we can picture color without it being presented to the public world of physics. And what we immediately perceive (and what we picture) are ideas.
If I say that the pillow in my room is perceivable, you will agree, though neither of us are (I hope!) in my room (please get out if you are). Yet, all we have to do is enter my room, turn on the light, and the pillow will be there to see. This is never the case for "matter" defined by the materialist as we've done. That is why likeness principle undercuts such a materialist theory. "An idea can be like nothing but an idea; a colour or figure can be like nothing but another colour or figure."
Hence, Berkeley's famous (so-called) "master argument" (Principles, 22-23, and middleish of the first Dialogue). Pay attention to what one means. 'Sensible' cannot be truly applied to something without sensible qualities. But, anything with sensible qualities, or qualities that can actually be phenomenologically presented to a conscious subject of experience (mind, person, dog, cat, fish, God, etc.), is stipulated to be an idea by resemblance based indirect realists. Hence, any way you swing it, materialists like Descartes, Locke, and Malebranche, among others, cannot maintain their position without contradiction or vacuity. For, they cannot even "conceive it possible for a sound, or figure, or motion, or colour to exist without the mind or unperceived" (Principles, 22). Hence, I maintain that there is no good response to Berkeley's likeness principle. I am convinced that the principle is sound. QED.
And Bob's your uncle.

As someone new here, first welcome. Second +1. I just touched on idealism here. Third a bit of advice: If you reduce the length of your answer to half you'll have more than double the readers

It was never about reaching an audience. Thanks for your welcome.
